# TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings, fasta-to-gtf python script

Tags: python, fasta

I am using code sourced from github, not my own, to make a gtf file for non model organism using a reference genome and de novo transcriptome assembly (both fasta files). I changed the paths for my files in the script and receive an error when I try to run.

New to python so not sure what to do.

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess, getopt, sys,time



def usage():

    print("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n~~~~~~~fasta-to-gtf~~~~~~~\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")


def main():

    verbose=False

    assembly= Path(“/users/sf6/data/TMF8001-PmB-Agalma-14135260.BlastRef.fa”)

    output= “PmB.gtf”

    genome= Path(“/users/sf6/data/GCA_000285935.1_Pmin_1.0_genomic.fa”)

    try:

        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "o:g:a:hv", ["help", "verbose", "output=", "genome=", "assembly="])

    except:

        print 'fasta-to-gtf.py Says:     Unable to parse arguments.'

        usage()

        sys.exit()




    for option, value in opts:

        if option in ("-h", "--help"):

            usage()

            sys.exit()

        elif option in ("-o", "--output"):

            output = value

            print output

        elif option in ("-g", "--genome"):

            genome = value

            print genome

        elif option in ("-a", "--assembly"):

            assembly = value

            print assembly

        elif option in ("-v", "--verbose"):

            verbose = True

        else:

            assert False, 'Unrecognized option: known options are -v,-h,-o,-g,-a'

    if output == None or genome==None or assembly==None:

        print('fasta-to-gtf.py Says:     All three fields -g -a -o must be specified...')

        sys.exit()




    blat_command = "blat %s %s temp_output.psl -t=dna -q=dna -tileSize=11 -minIdentity=90 -maxIntron=1001 -out=psl" % (genome, assembly)

    if verbose: 

        print("fasta-to-gtf.py Says:     Starting BLAT using transcripts from %s as queries to map to the reference genome %s ..." % (assembly,genome))

        print("fasta-to-gtf.py Says:     Running "+blat_command)




    subprocess.call(['blat', genome, assembly, 'temp_output.psl', '-t=dna','-q=dna','-tileSize=11','-minIdentity=90','-maxIntron=1001','-out=psl'])

    if verbose:

        print('fasta-to-gtf.py Says:     BLAT finished; parsing output...')

    with open('temp_output.psl','r') as blat_output:

        with open(output,'w') as outfile:

            if verbose:

                print 'fasta-to-gtf.py Says:     Generating GTF file...'



            for line in blat_output:

                if line[0].isdigit():  #checks if line is header or not

                    #blast format:

                    try:

                        split_line= line.split("\t")

                        matches=split_line[0]

                        misMatches=split_line[1]

                        repMatches=split_line[2] 

                        nCount=split_line[3]

                        qNumInsert=split_line[4] 

                        qBaseInsert=split_line[5] 

                        tNumInsert=split_line[6]

                        tBaseInsert=split_line[7]

                        strand=split_line[8]

                        qName=split_line[9] 

                        qSize=split_line[10] 

                        qStart=split_line[11] 

                        qEnd=split_line[12] 

                        tName=split_line[13] 

                        tSize=split_line[14]

                        tStart=split_line[15]

                        tEnd=split_line[16]

                    except:

                        print("Unable to convert the following line from psl to gtf:%s\n" % (line))

                    #gtf format: seqname, source, feature, start, end, score, strand, frame, attribute (with semicolon separated stuff)

                    attributes=qName+";"+qSize

                    if misMatches =="0":

                        perc_ident="100"

                    else:

                        perc_ident=str(100*int(matches)/(int(misMatches)+int(matches)))



                    outfile.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (tName, "BLAT\ttranscript", tStart, tEnd, perc_ident, strand, '0', attributes))



        outfile.close()

    blat_output.close()

    subprocess.call(['rm','temp_output.psl'])

    if verbose:

        print 'fasta-to-gtf.py Says:     Finished.'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

For reference, I am using a Mac, and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makegtf.py", line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "makegtf.py", line 107, in main
    subprocess.call(['blat', genome, assembly, 'temp_output.psl', '-t=dna','-q=dna','-tileSize=11','-minIdentity=90','-maxIntron=1001','-out=psl'])
  File "/gpfs/runtime/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/gpfs/runtime/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/gpfs/runtime/opt/python/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Comment: What are the types of `genome` and `assembly` in the command?  Try adding a line `print type(genome), type(assembly)` immediately above the `subprocess.call([...])` line.

Comment: I tried adding the line and received the same error message. I'm not sure what you mean by type? They are both fastas, the genome is from ncbi and the assembly is a de novo assembly done in the lab.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion

Comment: I would expect the same error message.  What this line would print out would be the type of value (e.g. `string` or `int`)  in `genome` and `assembly`.

Answer (score 1):

Having a closer look at your code, I notice the following lines:

```
    assembly= Path("/users/sf6/data/TMF8001-PmB-Agalma-14135260.BlastRef.fa")

    # ...

    genome= Path("/users/sf6/data/GCA_000285935.1_Pmin_1.0_genomic.fa")

    # ...

    subprocess.call(['blat', genome, assembly, 'temp_output.psl', '-t=dna','-q=dna','-tileSize=11','-minIdentity=90','-maxIntron=1001','-out=psl'])
```

Here we can see that `assembly` and `genome` are both `Path` objects.

The error message says `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`, which is a perhaps-cryptic way of saying that `subprocess.call([...])` needs all of its arguments  to be strings but some of them aren't.  Indeed this is the case: `genome` and `assembly` aren't strings, they're `Path` objects.

To fix the problem we must convert these arguments to strings.  To convert a path object `some_path` to a string, use `str(some_path)`.  Try replacing the `subprocess.call([...])` line with

```
    subprocess.call(['blat', str(genome), str(assembly), 'temp_output.psl', '-t=dna','-q=dna','-tileSize=11','-minIdentity=90','-maxIntron=1001','-out=psl'])
```

(Within the code I omitted above, there are lines that assign values to `genome` or `assembly` from command-line arguments, but I would expect these values to be strings.  Given that you're getting the error you mention, I can only assume that at least one of `genome` or `assembly` is not being read in from a command-line argument and is being left as the `Path` object you initialise these variables with.)